# cannot use composes in *.scss files (react-css-modules) - Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'postcss' of null

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, css-modules, css-loader

when I try use composes in a class .topContainer  i have error in console when building project:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"modules":true,"localIdentName":"[local]--[hash:base64:5]","importLoaders":2}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":true,"plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/public/scss/layout.scss
>
> Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'postcss' of null
>
> at Processor.normalize (/home/projects/myproject/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:136:12)
>
> at new Processor (/home/projects/myproject/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:51:25)
>
> at postcss (/home/projects/myproject/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:73:10)
>
> at Promise.resolve.then.then (/home/projects/myproject/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js:146:12)
>        @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"modules":true,"localIdentName":"[local]--[hash:base64:5]","importLoaders":2}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":true,"plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/containers/layout/Header/styles.scss 3:10-350 12:42-382

it's a react web application:
[web app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4biS.jpg)
I use sass and settings webpack.config:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/myproject')
    ],
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                importLoaders: 2,
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                plugins: [autoprefixer()],
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
    ])
},
```

public/scss/layout.scss:

```
.mediaContainer {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

containers/layout/Header/styles.scss:

```
.top {
    &Container {
        composes: mediaContainer from '../../../public/scss/layout.scss';
    }
}
```